# Unable to proceed after clicking a button

Tags: selenium, electron, selenium-chromedriver, slack, spectron

I am using spectron to simulate a test on Slack as follows:

1) Open the application.
 2) Type in a valid domain.
 3) Click Continue.

I am using the following script for that purpose:

**JavaScript**:

```
var Application = require('spectron').Application
var assert = require('assert')

var app = new Application({
 path: '/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome'
})

app.start().then(function() {
 // Check if the window is visible
 return app.browserWindow.isVisible()
}).then(function(isVisible) {
 // Verify the window is visible
 assert.equal(isVisible, true)
}).then(function() {
 // Get the window's title
 return app.client.getTitle()
}).then(function(title) {
 // Verify the window's title
 // assert.equal(title, 'My App')
}).catch(function(error) {
 // Log any failures
 console.error('Test failed', error.message)
}).then(function() {
 // Stop the application
 // return app.stop()
})

console.log('Before setTimeout');

setTimeout(function() {
 console.log('Inside setTimeout');
 return app.client.waitUntilWindowLoaded()
 .windowHandles().then(function(session) {
 // Need to return the promise back, if promise is
 // it would wait for the state or else app will exit.
 console.log('Before switchTab, click & keys');
 app.client.switchTab(session.value[1]).click('#domain').keys('testing').click("#submit_team_domain")
 .catch(function(error) {
 console.error('error message->', error.message);
 });
 console.log('After switchTab, click & keys');
 });
}, 5000);
```

**Java**:

```
Set<String> windowHandles = webDriver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterator = windowHandles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
  String windowHandle = iterator.next();
  if (!windowHandle.equalsIgnoreCase(webDriver.getWindowHandle()))
    webDriver.switchTo().window(windowHandle);
}

try {
  Thread.sleep(5000);
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}

WebElement textBox = webDriver.findElement(By.id("domain"));
textBox.click();
textBox.sendKeys("testing");

WebElement button = webDriver.findElement(By.id("submit_team_domain"));
button = webDriver.findElement(By.id("submit_team_domain"));
button.click();
```

I am testing with and without a selenium server between a Mac and a Linux machine. The expected result should be that the page should proceed after  clicking continue.

What is actually happening is that if a valid domain is provided then it gets stuck and never proceeds. The only exception to this is when we use Spectron to test without a Selenium server on a Linux machine, which itself fails about 20% of the time.

If we provide an invalid domain in any of the cases, it simply proceeds.

Following are the logs when using Spectron without a Selenium Server:

```
requestOptions -> {"path":"/session/:sessionId/element"}
data -> {"using":"id","value":"domain"}
_ref -> {"body":{"sessionId":"bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.006260871409230262-1"}},"response":{"statusCode":200,"body":{"sessionId":"bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.006260871409230262-1"}},"headers":{"content-length":"104","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","connection":"close"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"127.0.0.1:9515","port":"9515","hostname":"127.0.0.1","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element","path":"/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element","href":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element"},"method":"POST","headers":{"Connection":"keep-alive","Accept":"application/json","User-Agent":"webdriverio/webdriverio/4.6.2","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","Content-Length":31}}}}

requestOptions -> {"path":"/session/:sessionId/element/0.006260871409230262-1/click","method":"POST"}
data -> {}
_ref -> {"body":{"sessionId":"bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f","status":0,"value":null},"response":{"statusCode":200,"body":{"sessionId":"bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f","status":0,"value":null},"headers":{"content-length":"72","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","connection":"close"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"127.0.0.1:9515","port":"9515","hostname":"127.0.0.1","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element/0.006260871409230262-1/click","path":"/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element/0.006260871409230262-1/click","href":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element/0.006260871409230262-1/click"},"method":"POST","headers":{"Connection":"keep-alive","Accept":"application/json","User-Agent":"webdriverio/webdriverio/4.6.2","content-type":"application/json","content-length":2}}}}
WARNING: the "keys" command will be depcrecated soon. Please use a different command in order to avoid failures in your test after updating WebdriverIO.

requestOptions -> {"path":"/session/:sessionId/keys"}
data -> {"value":["c","o","s","m","o","t","e","s","t","i","n","g"]}
_ref -> {"body":{"sessionId":"bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f","status":0,"value":null},"response":{"statusCode":200,"body":{"sessionId":"bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f","status":0,"value":null},"headers":{"content-length":"72","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","connection":"close"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"127.0.0.1:9515","port":"9515","hostname":"127.0.0.1","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/keys","path":"/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/keys","href":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/keys"},"method":"POST","headers":{"Connection":"keep-alive","Accept":"application/json","User-Agent":"webdriverio/webdriverio/4.6.2","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","Content-Length":59}}}}

requestOptions -> {"path":"/session/:sessionId/element"}
data -> {"using":"id","value":"submit_team_domain"}
_ref -> {"body":{"sessionId":"bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.006260871409230262-2"}},"response":{"statusCode":200,"body":{"sessionId":"bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.006260871409230262-2"}},"headers":{"content-length":"104","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","connection":"close"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"127.0.0.1:9515","port":"9515","hostname":"127.0.0.1","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element","path":"/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element","href":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element"},"method":"POST","headers":{"Connection":"keep-alive","Accept":"application/json","User-Agent":"webdriverio/webdriverio/4.6.2","Content-Type":"application/json; charset=UTF-8","Content-Length":43}}}}

requestOptions -> {"path":"/session/:sessionId/element/0.006260871409230262-2/click","method":"POST"}
data -> {}
_ref -> {"body":{"sessionId":"bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f","status":0,"value":null},"response":{"statusCode":200,"body":{"sessionId":"bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f","status":0,"value":null},"headers":{"content-length":"72","content-type":"application/json; charset=utf-8","connection":"close"},"request":{"uri":{"protocol":"http:","slashes":true,"auth":null,"host":"127.0.0.1:9515","port":"9515","hostname":"127.0.0.1","hash":null,"search":null,"query":null,"pathname":"/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element/0.006260871409230262-2/click","path":"/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element/0.006260871409230262-2/click","href":"http://127.0.0.1:9515/wd/hub/session/bc8bc9abd7a9827258cee72de70d835f/element/0.006260871409230262-2/click"},"method":"POST","headers":{"Connection":"keep-alive","Accept":"application/json","User-Agent":"webdriverio/webdriverio/4.6.2","content-type":"application/json","content-length":2}}}}
```

Following are the logs when using Java Language Bindings with a Selenium Server:

```
15:11:43.884 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession@5d54be3a
15:11:43.884 INFO - Handler thread for session 976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c (chrome): Executing POST on /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element (handler: ServicedSession)
15:11:43.885 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"domain"}
15:11:43.885 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@55edb1c210 pairs: {POST /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_151)}{Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{Host: localhost:25846}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Content-Length: 31}
15:11:43.908 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@61b2a16b4 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Content-Length: 102}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}
15:11:43.908 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.8306467617329649-1"}}

15:11:43.917 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession@5d54be3a
15:11:43.917 INFO - Handler thread for session 976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c (chrome): Executing POST on /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element/0.8306467617329649-1/click (handler: ServicedSession)
15:11:43.918 INFO - To upstream: {"id":"0.8306467617329649-1"}
15:11:43.919 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@3cbdbdb110 pairs: {POST /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element/0.8306467617329649-1/click HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_151)}{Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{Host: localhost:25846}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Content-Length: 29}
15:11:43.986 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@32f13174 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Content-Length: 72}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}
15:11:43.986 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c","status":0,"value":null}

15:11:43.991 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession@5d54be3a
15:11:43.991 INFO - Handler thread for session 976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c (chrome): Executing POST on /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element (handler: ServicedSession)
15:11:43.992 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"domain"} 
15:11:43.992 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@3bf4c11110 pairs: {POST /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_151)}{Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{Host: localhost:25846}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Content-Length: 31}
15:11:43.998 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@4f3986fd4 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Content-Length: 102}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}
15:11:43.998 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.8306467617329649-1"}}

15:11:44.002 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession@5d54be3a
15:11:44.002 INFO - Handler thread for session 976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c (chrome): Executing POST on /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element/0.8306467617329649-1/value (handler: ServicedSession)
15:11:44.003 INFO - To upstream: {"id":"0.8306467617329649-1","value":["cosmotesting"]}
15:11:44.003 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@1eb8ea9e10 pairs: {POST /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element/0.8306467617329649-1/value HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_151)}{Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{Host: localhost:25846}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Content-Length: 54}
15:11:44.032 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@65f4e5f54 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Content-Length: 72}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}
15:11:44.032 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c","status":0,"value":null}

15:11:44.036 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession@5d54be3a
15:11:44.036 INFO - Handler thread for session 976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c (chrome): Executing POST on /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element (handler: ServicedSession)
15:11:44.036 INFO - To upstream: {"using":"id","value":"submit_team_domain"}
15:11:44.036 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@78955c1310 pairs: {POST /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_151)}{Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{Host: localhost:25846}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Content-Length: 43}
15:11:44.050 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@7b1823924 pairs: {null: HTTP/1.1 200 OK}{Content-Length: 102}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}
15:11:44.050 INFO - To downstream: {"sessionId":"976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c","status":0,"value":{"ELEMENT":"0.8306467617329649-2"}}

15:11:44.054 INFO - Found handler: org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ServicedSession@5d54be3a
15:11:44.054 INFO - Handler thread for session 976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c (chrome): Executing POST on /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element/0.8306467617329649-2/click (handler: ServicedSession)
15:11:44.055 INFO - To upstream: {"id":"0.8306467617329649-2"}
15:11:44.055 DEBUG - sun.net.www.MessageHeader@22adda7510 pairs: {POST /session/976706a5ace12e22ec54d9848f21813c/element/0.8306467617329649-2/click HTTP/1.1: null}{User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.3 (Java/1.8.0_151)}{Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate}{Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8}{Connection: close}{Cache-Control: no-cache}{Pragma: no-cache}{Host: localhost:25846}{Accept: text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2, */*; q=.2}{Content-Length: 29}
```